# Haar measure over quotient spaces

Tags: integration, group-theory, notation, haar-measure

In equation 23 of the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10743.pdf, the Haar integration over the quotient space $G/H$ is defined as follows

$$\int_{G / H} f(x) d x=\int_{G} f(g H) d g$$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Can anyone explain what does the notation $f(gH)$ where $g \in G$ stand for ? And can anybody justify the above formula ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General elements of $G/H$ are usually written as left cosets. That is, $G/H=\{ gH : g \in G\}$. Now, you are integrating a measurable function $f: G/H \to \Bbb{C}$ over $G/H$, so it makes sense to talk about $f(gH)$. In fact when you put $f(x)$ you are assuming that $x\in G/H$, so $x$ looks like $gH$ for some $g\in G$. Notice that the map $g\mapsto f(gH)$ is now a measurable function from $G$ to $\Bbb{C}$, and you already have a Haar measure on $G$. That way, the formula you write is just telling you a way to integrate over $G/H$ using the Haar measure on $G$.

Comment: Doesn't $gH$ describe a set rather than an element? Are you trying to say $f(gH)$ means $f(gh)$ for some $h \in H$?

Comment: Yes $gH=\{gh: h\in H\}$ is a set, but elements of $G/H$ are sets. Recall that $G/H$ is the set of equivalence clases of the relation $g\sim g’ \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}g’\in H$, so each equivalence class $[g]$ is the set $gH$.

Comment: Are you trying to say $f$ is a class function ?

Comment: You are integrating $f$ over $G/H$, that means that the domain of $f$ is $G/H$. In other words, $f$ takes the set $gH \in G/H$ and maps it to the scalar $f(gH)\in \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.